# Analytics and search Geospatial data (Big Data)

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, elasticsearch, cassandra, bigdata

At my company we are about to store a big amount of geo-location data coming from mobile GPS.

The requirements are :

1) To be able to to keep these data to our database for at least six months (history)

2) Clients can perform search queries in real time. That means we need to perform some spatial functions on them

3) to be able to analyze data and path of points in order we can have a good average of the older points in these six months.

We think about Hadoop file System in order to save data and  use mapReduce for analize them. For real time queries we thinking about elasticsearch (SPATIAL FUNCTIONS AND INDEX ) or Mongodb or Cassandra.

What do you think should be the approach in this scenario ?

Comment: ****anyone?****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, MongoDB can be used for realtime analytics as MongoDB provides with Built-In "geoNear" based geoSpatial queries. Have a look at GeoSpatial data and how it is addressed by MongoDB at this Link : http://blog.mlab.com/2014/08/a-primer-on-geospatial-data-and-mongodb/